# Where can I find the application executables in the filesystem?

Tags: filesystem, executable

Where are executables for programs stored in Ubuntu?

An application (Komodo Edit) is asking me to identify an application to be used as a web browser. I've become used to just entering the application name as a command for situations such as these, but this scenario got me thinking.

I know in Windows it would just be the relevant application folder in the 'program files' folder, but I'm assuming things are a bit different on Linux?

I thought somewhere like `bin` would be logical but this appears to standard Linux/Unix applications. Where would I find the binary executable for applications stored on my system?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

The complete answer is to check out the [Filesystem Hierachy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html) documentation on what stuff goes where.

But in your case, if you want to know where a particular executable is (for example firefox) use

```
which firefox
```

And you will get the full path like this

```
/usr/bin/firefox
```

Comment: `Filesystem Hierachy Standard`... interesting...  I won't be going through it with a fine-tooth comb, but its definitely good to know about it... It has given me another notch of insight into Linux...

Answer (score 12):

Applications installed through the package manager usually go to `/usr/bin`. Applications you compile yourself go to `/usr/local/bin/` unless you explicitly set a different prefix when compiling.

You can find out where a specific application lives by typing `which application_name` into the terminal. E.g. `which firefox` will print `/usr/bin/firefox` (if you're using firefox from the Ubuntu packages).

Answer (score 6):

A good CLI commad for this kind of questions is:

```
whereis <nameofwhatever>
```

or, of course which (see below)

Comment: This will find files named <nameofwhatever> which may or may not be executables. Some may even be directories. You should use which in place of whereis.

Comment: Full ACK for standard installations (that we all hopefully have).

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this if you're looking for the executable from a package name:

```
dpkg -L firefox
```

This will list all files owned by firefox. To get the executables, pass it through further processing

```
dpkg -L firefox | while IFS=$'\n' read -r line; do
    [[ -x "${line#*:}" ]] && echo "$line"
done
```